# How overcome lack of experience in native tools

Tags: interviewing, new-job, applications, career-switch

I'm in the beginning process of looking for something new in my career. I am a ios/android engineer with about 3 years experience in mobile development and I *think* I've really rocked out my first few phone interviews thus far.

I have a lot of experience handling projects from all aspects of the SDLC. In fact I handle everything from analysis... to database stuff... to coding to deployment on the app store for all my projects. At 3 years in, I believe this is my biggest advantage over other applicants.... But, all my experience in iOS/Android hasn't been in native tools. No experience in Swift/Objective-C or Java (although I studied Objective-C and Java both in college).

Of course, the majority if not all the openings I see for iOS/Android developers on in native tools, but **how can I overcome my lack of specific experience in those coding languages**? I assume, and have taken the approach so far to stress not only my ability to learn (which I was asked to do in this non-native language) and succeed so far, but also to stress my widen experiences so far given my responsibilities as a developer that handles so much if not everything on projects for my company.

One thing to note: yes, I do want to transition into native tools, hence why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say 'native tools'?

Comment: Perhaps you find the companies in ways other than going through HR?

Comment: @Ryan, there are cross-platform tools like Xamarin, PhoneGap and Cordova that could let me write in C# the code for a mobile application for iOS or Android without doing anything in Objective-C or Java, which have their own tools that could be used to build the app directly rather than use a framework that translates various pieces for me.

Comment: I'm confused about the downvotes here? Seems like a legitimate concern...

Comment: I think even Ryan's comment legitimizes my concern and reasoning for a question.. But yes, JB King is right. I use Delphi to develop for Android/iOS

Comment: @user43390, btw, if you're in a metro area, go to meetups for tools you do use. You'll find talks by companies who use those tools, which are your best bets for finding relevant places.

Comment: "how can I overcome my lack of specific experience in those coding languages" - One thing you could do: take something that you've already finished in another tool/language and then re-implement it in the new language/tool that you are using. Doing this might seem pointless at first, but you will learn the new tool and probably also learn something about the existing project at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your level of experience, developing an app in github will go a long way to getting you the experience you need, if you can invest the time prior to the interview.  That way you can show professional experience for the full SDLC in your work experience, and some level of mastery of the native tooling on the side. Few places will actually be concerned that you weren't paid for that particular language skill, code usually speaks for itself.

Many places are moving to React Native, which is only partially native, so it might help to emphasize (read: boldly assert) that you bring that type of experience to the table.

Answer (score 3):

most job openings in mobile development are in either Java for Android or Swift/Objective C for IOS because most cross party tools are not very good once you get beyond simple apps and are often broken when Apple or Google update their SDKs.

Your best bet is to go in at a junior/graduate level as either a iOS or Android developer using the native languages and start coding commercially. A github repo helps but commercial experience is much more important. You should be able to pick it up quickly with your experience so you won't have to stay long as a junior.